# Place to variable an information from another column SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox

I created Windows Forms application with 1 ComboBox.
Then connected this ComboBox to SQL table (there 2 columns: ID and NAME). So I recieve automatic filled ComboBox with NAME-column.

QUESTION: How can I place ID of current element in variable? Maybe on Button click.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends on how you wanna use it later, what's your current setup, how you fill that ComboBox.But you can check ID and assign it using SelectedValue property of ComboBox

Comment: There a project: [link](https://yadi.sk/d/7Zlg0dFzqPops) This is connecting DataBase: [link](https://yadi.sk/i/tQ9p-QXuqPotb) and [link](https://yadi.sk/i/wVfMCcWfqPovZ) This is SQL code: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
 [ID] [int] NULL,
 [NAME] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.
It's was so close :)

```
var perem = comboBox1.SelectedValue
```

[image]